# How to dynamically transfer values from a drop down list to a DataTable?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm not really sure how to dynamically transfer the values from a DropDown list to a jquery DataTable in a way that when i choose a value from the list that once transfered doesn't appear in the DropDown list anymore, but if i remove it from the datatable that it appears back. The DropDown list is populated with the users from a database table and each user has his own id. I need the list values to not appear in the view, the backend is ok, i was thinking it could be done with javascript but i'm not sure how.
I don't have any code as i don't have the slightest idea as to how to make it, i'm still rather new to coding so any help is welcome.

Comment: any tried code to be look into?

Comment: Can't able to understand what you exactly want. Is your DropDown come with DataTable or is it outside of DataTable ? Suppose I select 1 value from DropDown then which field in DataTable you want to change (Is it a textBox or what) ??

Comment: No the dropdown is not in the datatable, the dropdown has a list of values which when i chose one and click a button which adds it i want to transfer to the datatable. And i want it transfered to a row. I chose the name of a person in the dropdownlist and transfer the name into the datatable row, but i don't have an idea as to how to make the code in javascript for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy if I understood your question properly.

Add a class to your column where you want to display the value after change from drop down. For example,

```
//my rest code for DataTable
"columns": [
            {
             "render": function (data, type, row) {
              return "<input type='text'  class='myDropDownValue'>";
                }
            },
            //Rest columns
```

In DropDown change event just render the value to this class, like bellow,

```
$('#myDropDown').change(function(){
  var myValue = $(this).val();
  //here we can render this value to data table row
  $('.myDropDownValue').html('');
  $('.myDropDownValue').val(myValue);
})
```

That's it!

Comment: Glad that it helped you :)